# Additional Line impacting dependent drop downs

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have an issue when adding a line into a sheet where it kicks the drop down dependencies out of order.
Column E is a list of option dependent on the input of column D. All works fine, referencing a master data sheet.
However, when I insert a row into the "Team Activity Recording" tab, it copies the data validation from the above row and throws all subsequent rows out of alignment for the data validation.
EG Row 8 references Row 8 on the data drop down sheet, row 9 references row 9 and so on. If I insert a row above 9, both the new row 9 and row 10 reference row 9 on the data sheet.
I would like to know how I can add and remove rows in the "Team Activity Recording" tab and maintain the correct data validation?

[Test Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w9TrdphNt08w4guG_i7TDmf3JTTBDAvqbI3yoJRT89A/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0):

Each time you insert or remove a row, you will need to reapply the **Data Validation** for your dependent lists.

1. Copy a working range, e.g. `D7:E7`
2. Select the entire range, e.g. `D7:E21`
3. Paste **Validation Only** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>s</kbd> then <kbd>d</kbd>

The alternative is to use scripting and a trigger to do this for you.